# what the procedure of display image in particular UItableview(grouped) cell iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what the procedure of display image in particular UItableview(grouped) cell iphone ?

Comment: you want to display the image in header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:urImage];
[cell setBackgroundView:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 0):

The document [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) provides in depth explanation and example code. It's worth reading.